# What is the substitute of IgnoreRoute and RouteExistingFiles in .Net Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

ASP.NET MVC had Methods RouteExistingFiles and IgnoreRoute on RoutesCollection:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*relpath}", new { relpath = @"(.*)?\.(css|js|htm|html)" });
```

ASP.NET Core does not have these methods anymore. How can I let static files serve before dynamic content?

Comment: Add the StaticFiles middleware to pipepline before mvc. You can read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#serving-static-files)